# PHP Printing a string with multiple single quotes

Tags: php, escaping, html-escape-characters

So I'm having an issue that seems like it should be a pretty simple fix but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm using prepared statements to query data from my SQL and the return is correct. I have `var_dumped` the result and confirmed the the information is there.

The table shows this: 2 'all of the way'

The array variable shows this: 2 \'all of the way\'

But when I echo it to the page, I see this: 2

I have tried `htmlspecialchars`, `htmlentities`, `addslashes`, `stripslashes` and a few combinations of those. Is there a function I'm missing here? Google isn't really helpful because the words to describe the problem are pretty generic.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Sorry - didn't add my code because I assumed it was a function I wasn't familiar with. Here it is.

```
        $Res = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM 01_02_item WHERE ParID = $ParID AND active = 1 ORDER BY OrderID") -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(empty($Res[0])) $return = "<span class = 'nodata'>No data</span>";
        foreach($Res as $r){
            $id = $r['id'];
            $name = htmlspecialchars($r['Name']);
            $title = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($r['Description']));
            $return .= "<li href = '$id' title = '$title' name = '$name'>$name</li>";
        }
        return $return;
```

Comment: Please post the PHP code that you're using to `echo` this to the screen...

Comment: Hard to help with no code. Please post it.

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars($r['Description'],ENT_QUOTES)` instead. See if that works. Whoops, @GrasDouble said it before me.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) doesn't escape single quotes.

You should use `htmlspecialchars('foobar', ENT_QUOTES)`.